# Django - Javascript does not load

Tags: javascript, django

I have seen so many questions and answers on this but nothing is working.

I have a base.html which looks like so:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello Django</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style2.css" %}">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/main.js" %}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
{% block js %}{% endblock %}

</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}


</body>
</html>
```

I then have a template which looks like so:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block javascript %}
<script>
 alert("hello");
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
```

In both cases, 1) The JavaScript file main.js is not loaded in. If I look at the DOM, the JavaScript file is not there. If I add in another CSS file, that works fine. Its just JavaScript.

2) The JavaScript in the block in the template doesn't run either.

Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your main template declares a block called "js" but your child template has a block called "javascript". These need to be the same.

Comment: Why would that stop my main.js file loading in the header?

Comment: It wouldn't. Are you sure your JS file is in the right place? Show your folder structure.

Comment: It would give me a error 404 if it couldn't find it. It doesn't attempt to load it.

Comment: I have added the file structure